# what is zsh: exec format error in redhat?

Tags: executable

```
zsh: exec format error...
```

his is the error I was getting when trying to execute a large application. I am using redhat Linux.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of `file` for the file you're trying to execute?  (`file <filename>`)

Comment: A quick Google shows that this can be caused when you attempt to run the incorrect architecture application - for example, attempting to run a x64 application on a 32-bit distro. With so little information in your question, it's very difficult to guess what your particular cause is.

Comment: // , Note that this is error number 8.

Answer (score 29):

The file that you're running has been given the execute permission, but it isn't in a format that the kernel understands, so it can't be executed on your machine.

Run `file /path/to/the/executable` to see what kind of a file it is.

This could be an archive that you're supposed to extract, or an executable for a different architecture (e.g. a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit system), or anything else really.

Comment: The problem was that I started downloading an installer (executable sh file) and executed it but it wasn't done downloading (size was 637 MB!) so yeah

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in shell script, by switch the file's line separator to \n, then it works for me.